# Add up all items from a list and restart from 0

Tags: haskell

Is it possible in Haskell to write a function which add up all items from an integer list and if a sum in the middle of the list is under 0, than restart add up with 0. I mean something like this:

```
[2,5,-6,-2,8,4]

2 + 5 =  7
7 - 6 =  1
1 - 2 = -1     restart here because we are under 0
0 + 8 =  8
8 + 4 = 12

function return 12
```

Of course I know that I can add up all items from a list with this code:

```
sum :: [Int] -> Int
sum [x]   = x
sum (x:l) = x + sum l
```

But I do not know how I can restart the function if a sum is under 0. Any ideas for that or is that not possible in an functional coding language because we don't have real variables or something else?

Comment: btw. your code has no definition for the base case,e.g. the empty list.

Comment: Haskell is Turing complete which essentially means that it can perform any computation that can be performed by any other language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very possible, you use an accumulator variable.

```
sumPos xs = go 0 xs where
  go acc [] = acc
  go acc (x:xs) = go (max (acc + x) 0) xs
```

This can be factored by built-in recursion functions like `foldl'` very nicely.

```
sumPos = foldl' step 0 where
  step x acc = max 0 (x + acc)
```

Or even `foldl' (max 0 .: (+)) 0` if you define `(.:) = (.).(.)` as some people like to.

Comment: Note that `maximum` is the list version of `max`.

Comment: Oh, whoops. I will fix that. I had been doing this previously on my phone.

Answer (score 3):

Let me use `scanl` to show what is going on and then `foldl` to get only the actual result.

First let us simply try to add all elements of the list:

```
Prelude> scanl (+) 0 [2,5,-6,-2,8,4]
[0,2,7,1,-1,7,11]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
Prelude> scanl (\a b -> a+b) 0 [2,5,-6,-2,8,4]
[0,2,7,1,-1,7,11]
```

To avoid negative intermediate numbers you can change it like this:

```
Prelude> scanl (\a b -> max 0 (a+b)) 0 [2,5,-6,-2,8,4]
[0,2,7,1,0,8,12]
```

To get only the actual result, replace `scanl` by `foldl`:

```
Prelude> foldl (\a b -> max 0 (a+b)) 0 [2,5,-6,-2,8,4]
12
```